# Adding UI elements between elements using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, autolayout

I have two UIViews using autolayout . All the constraints are defined in the xib. How do we add another view between view 1 and view 2 using autolayout without any conflicts.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to demote the constraint between view 1 and view 2. Either make it a low priority or change the equals constant to less than or equals. Alternatively you can save an outlet reference to that constraint and remove it when the new view is added.

```
    // Add the view as subview
    [self.view addSubview:view3];
    [view3 setTranslatesAutoresizingMasksIntoConstraints:NO]

    // Make the constraints
    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view1, view2, view3);
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[view1]-10-[view3]-10-[view2]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[view3]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    // Tell view to update
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

If you are animating the view into place, you'll want to do all the same except put only that last line in the animation block. You may also want to set a starting frame for the view or else it will animate from the top left corner by default.